# Need Comma seperated output for a query fetching mutiple rows

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Query:

```
select o.candidateid 
from onboardingcandidates o, candidatedetails c 
where o.candidateid=c.candidateid 
    and o.JOININGSTATUS='0091' 
    and to_date(o.joiningdate)=to_date(sysdate+5);

Output:

cand1
cand2
cand3
cand62

Required Output:

cand1, cand2, cand3, cand62
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use **[LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm)**

```
SELECT LISTAGG(o.candidateid) WITHIN GROUP () .....
```

- [**SEE SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37b70/5)